# building web application with eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java

im having a problem running my deployed application on tomcat am getting an error : Message:
FAIL - Application at context path /website could not be started.

My web.xml is  like this:

```
enter code here <?xml version="1.0"?> <web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns"xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sum.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>website.web.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please advice what i did wrong.

Comment: Look in your logfiles.

Comment: i just checked and the error is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\website does not exist or is not a readable directory

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (and what worked for me) was to delete my tomcat server from the "Servers" view in Eclipse, then create a new server and run the application. It worked for me